# how to extends org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.javaeditor and create our own Java Script Editor with cutom javaScript tags

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

How to extends "org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.javaeditor" and create our own Java Script Editor with cutom javaScript tags ?

Comment: What is a non-custom JavaScript 'tag'?

Comment: I have written a javascript libary...                                    It's contains cutom java script code blocks such as Titanium Appcelerator. so i want to add the intellisense support for my javascriptlibary by writing an eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jseditor/

The project is an Eclipse plugin that provides an editor for JavaScript files with syntax highlighting and outlining including some common OO approaches. Supported OO outline features are: Constructor, Class methods, Instance methods, Class variables etc